# Diferença entre function e Function

Tags: javascript, funções

Comecei a estudar Js recentemente e estou na dúvida entre o uso de `function` e `Function`.

Comment: Em qual contexto? Edite a sua pergunta e dê mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

`function` é uma palavra chave do Javascript utilizada para definir uma nova função, já o [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) faz referência a classe. Funções em Javascript são objetos de primeira classe, portando cada função que você cria é um novo objeto.

```js
function soma(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

const somaPorInstanciacao = new Function("a", "b", `
  return a + b;
`);

console.log(soma(1, 2));
console.log(somaPorInstanciacao(1, 2));
```